# Solution for "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "null" does not exist" while using pivot in Dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I used following expression for converting rows to columns in dataframes using Scala:

```scala
val df = Seq(  
  ("ID-1", "First Name", "Jolly"),  
  ("ID-1", "Middle Name", "Jr"),  
  ("ID-1", "Last Name", "Hudson"),  
  ("ID-2", "First Name", "Kathy"),  
  ("ID-2", "Last Name", "Oliver"),  
  ("ID-3", "Last Name", "Short"),  
  ("ID-3", "Middle Name", "M"),  
  ("ID-4", "First Name", "Denver")  
).toDF("ID", "Title", "Values")  

df.filter($"Title" isin ("First Name", "Last Name", "Middle Name")).
  groupBy("ID").pivot("Title").agg(first($"Values")).   
  select( $"ID", $"First Name", $"Last Name", $"Middle Name").  
  show(false) 


 // +----+----------+---------+-----------+  
 // |ID  |First Name|Last Name|Middle Name|  
 // +----+----------+---------+-----------+  
 // |ID-1|Jolly     |Hudson   |Jr         |
 // |ID-3|null      |Short    |M          |
 // |ID-4|Denver    |null     |null       |
 // |ID-2|Kathy     |Oliver   |null       |
 // +----+----------+---------+-----------+
```

Output is as expected but ended up with an exception as follows :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "null" does not exist

Please help in understanding the reason for getting this exception after getting the expected output and solution to resolve this.

Following is the error logs:

```
2018-09-12 12:09:54 [Executor task launch worker-1] ERROR o.a.s.e.Executor - Exception in task 15.0 in stage 69.0 (TID 4453)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "null" does not exist.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$fieldIndex$1.apply(StructType.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$fieldIndex$1.apply(StructType.scala:233)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.fieldIndex(StructType.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema.fieldIndex(rows.scala:213)
    at gbam.refdata.dataquality.utils.DataQualityRule$class.getColumn(DataQualityRule.scala:147)
    at gbam.refdata.dataquality_rules2.VendorpartyAddress.getColumn(VendorpartyAddress.scala:27)
    at gbam.refdata.dataquality.utils.DataQualityRule$$anonfun$getMissing$1$1.apply(DataQualityRule.scala:153)
    at gbam.refdata.dataquality.utils.DataQualityRule$$anonfun$getMissing$1$1.apply(DataQualityRule.scala:153)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at gbam.refdata.dataquality.utils.DataQualityRule$class.getMissing$1(DataQualityRule.scala:152)
    at gbam.refdata.dataquality.utils.DataQualityRule$class.getBreaks(DataQualityRule.scala:156)
    at gbam.refdata.dataquality_rules2.VendorpartyAddress.getBreaks(VendorpartyAddress.scala:27)
    at gbam.refdata.dataquality_rules2.VendorpartyAddress$$anonfun$4.apply(VendorpartyAddress.scala:103)
    at gbam.refdata.dataquality_rules2.VendorpartyAddress$$anonfun$4.apply(VendorpartyAddress.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I tried from my side but didnt get any error apart from the expected output.Could you please check if that is the only piece of code you are using.If possible share the complete log and screenshot

Comment: Hi Chandan, I have attached the logs to the post and also there is a small change in the code too -  I was using filter to get only required values from column "Title" (Which is mandatory in my case). Please suggest if this causing the issue, if so what would be the solution

Comment: I am not able to create your issue as its working as expected for me.the error might be due to other lines of code post this operation